# Gem version conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error when I run 'bundle install':

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    google-drive (>= 0) ruby depends on
      middleman-core (>= 3.2.2) ruby depends on
        activesupport (~> 3.2.6) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (4.2.0)
```

I don't specify a version for the google-drive gemfile, but I do specify gem 'rails', '4.2.0'.

If I fail to specify a rails version, I get a really old version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `google-drive`. Run `bundle update google-drive`.

Comment: @KevinBrown in this case it's a solution for TS problem

Answer (score 0):

Well - it looks like I was using the wrong gem. It's **google_drive** not **google-drive**.